# Download video from new youtube 2015 via JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

How one can download videos by link from new 2015 yotube via JS or PHP scripting?

Comment: Please do some research before asking here. And show that you've done some research in your question.

Comment: And researching it would demonstrate that downloading videos from YouTube (that aren't your own) is a violation of the ToS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PHP checkout this library which should help you do it in a few lines of code.

https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader I used it back along worked as expected.

Not sure about JS, came across this library for nodejs which looks pretty similar https://github.com/fent/node-youtube-dl or via `npm install youtube-dl`